# how to use GLFW with openGL?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to compile a short openGl and GLFW code but I'm failing in..
I've included all the .h like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw2.h>
```

I'm on linux so I've made a :

```
sudo zypper install libglfw2
```

When I'm compiling like this :

```
 g++ main.cpp -lGLU
```

I have :

```
main.cpp:14:22: fatal error: GL/glfw2.h:Any file or directory
 #include <GL/glfw2.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've also tried to include `#include <GL/glfw3.h>` but without success.

This is my complet code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw2.h>

int main()
{
      if (glfwInit() == false)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "GLFW failed to initialise.\n");
          return (-1);
        }
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
      GLFWwindow* window;
      window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OPENGL", NULL, NULL);
      if (!window)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "Window failed to create\n");
          glfwTerminate();
          return (-1);
        }
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
      glewExperimental = true;
      if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
          return (-1);
        }
    return (0);
}
```

Could someone know what I have to do to compile my code ?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that `glfw2.h` is a valid file?

Comment: Because I've downloaded with zypper libglfw2 so I tried to include it..

Comment: So, you didn't notice the fact that all of the documentation for GLFW 2.x (apparently no longer online) and the various examples that ship with it all include `glfw.h`?

Comment: Are you trying to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `GL/glfw2.h` and never has been, and the code above uses the GLFW 3 API.  See [Renamed library and header file](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/moving.html#moving_renamed_files) for more information about header paths.

There is no reason to use GLFW 2 for new projects, so I would avoid the `libglfw2` package.  Instead see if there is a GLFW 3 package.